# Xsession hangs in sudo edubuntu-langpack-installer

Tags: xorg, login, gdm

After an upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, the graphical login stopped working. The display manager did not show up anymore.

After some `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and other things, that seems to work now again. However, now KDE/Plasma still does not seem to run properly.

Strangely, I don't see any `~/.xsession-errors`, so not sure really how to even debug this?

I noticed that the startup command seems to be `startplasma-x11`. When I run this manually, i.e. interactively, I noticed that it hangs in a `sudo`? So what does it do when it is not interactively? Also hang in `sudo`? And indeed, I restarted `gdm3` once more, and then I checked `pstree -a`, and I see:

```
  |-gdm3
  |   |-gdm-session-wor
  |   |   |-gdm-x-session --register-session --run-script /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
  |   |   |   |-Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -background none
 -noreset -keeptty...
  |   |   |   |   `-8*[{Xorg}]
  |   |   |   |-Xsession /etc/gdm3/Xsession /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
  |   |   |   |   `-sudo edubuntu-langpack-installer
  |   |   |   `-2*[{gdm-x-session}]
  |   |   `-2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
  |   `-2*[{gdm3}]
```

So, what the hell? It hangs there in `sudo`? This seems totally messed up. Why is it even possible in this startup script that it hangs there? And why don't I have any logs about this?

How can I fix this now?

This seems to belong to `edubuntu-live`. Maybe I just uninstall this...
**Edit** Unfortunately, this has no effect. It still hangs in the same `sudo`?
**Edit** Ok, there was still the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/51edubuntu_langpacks`, which was not removed for some reason... After just deleting (renaming) this file, it seems works fine now.

A bit meta: This is the PC of my dad. He did the upgrade and complained that login was not working anymore. How should he ever have debugged and fixed that? This seems like a extremely serious issue, that there is a potential hang in the login due to some older package which installed sth stupid to `Xsession.d`. Also, it's not so easy to fix it for him remotely. I don't see his screen. I just see what processes are running, and I can see the logs. I.e. no logs here in this case. Or often not sure which logs to look at...

Comment: @guiverc No sorry, this is a misunderstanding. My dad did not use `dist-upgrade` but the update dialog which popped up on his screen - so this was the official update procedure. I thought I can use the term "dist-upgrade" to also refer to that.